# Woocommerce: Add Custom Add to cart Ajax

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I'm building a mobile app and need a custom endpoint to add a product to the cart,

for normal products like `simple` or `variable` the default `wc-ajax=add_to-cart` works fine, but my customer using `yith composite product` plugin that adding new custom type product.

That product with type `composite` it's the parent and has children (other products like components )

Now the add to cart button on the product page for this type of product works for submitting the form inside and successfully added to the cart, but I need to do it with a custom endpoint to use it on my mobile app with no problems.

the form is inside the product page and action with the same product page URL.

Now how to add custom ajax handler to this type of product

The header ( form data ) of submitting the form add to cart was the following

```
ywcp_selection[153CE4EE-C1A0-6D39-9AD5-58B51C5AB306]: -1
attribute_pa_sphere: 7-50
ywcp_variation_id[153CE4EE-C1A0-6D39-9AD5-58B51C5AB306]: 124138
ywcp_quantity[153CE4EE-C1A0-6D39-9AD5-58B51C5AB306]: 1
ywcp_selected_product_value[153CE4EE-C1A0-6D39-9AD5-58B51C5AB306]: 102523
ywcp_selection[471BAD03-9C3B-B44E-8584-348A5F33F8A6]: -1
attribute_pa_sphere: 7-00
ywcp_variation_id[471BAD03-9C3B-B44E-8584-348A5F33F8A6]: 110356
ywcp_quantity[471BAD03-9C3B-B44E-8584-348A5F33F8A6]: 1
ywcp_selected_product_value[471BAD03-9C3B-B44E-8584-348A5F33F8A6]: 102552
quantity: 1
add-to-cart: 102491
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WooCommerce: How to add custom type product to cart with ajax by user JWT token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58860768/woocommerce-how-to-add-custom-type-product-to-cart-with-ajax-by-user-jwt-token)

Comment: I don't understand, there's no answer on the above link